# Line breaks in Slim Text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, text, slim-lang

How do I do a line break in a `.text.slim` before a variable?

```
| 
  Vous pouvez remonter votre offre en tête de liste afin de :
   * Booster la visibilité de votre offre
   * Bénéficier de 15 jours supplémentaires de diffusion

 =<> @job_offer_publish_url
```

​
I want to add a line break before the `@job_offer_publish_url` but `slim` doesn't handle it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution but not a pretty one...

```
| 
  Vous pouvez remonter votre offre en tête de liste afin de :
    * Booster la visibilité de votre offre
    * Bénéficier de 15 jours supplémentaires de diffusion

= '\n\n' + @job_offer_publish_url
```

I'll be happy to have something better !

Comment: I think that's pretty much going to be your only option with text. Aside from changing it to use string interpolation instead of concatenation: `= "\n\n#{@job_offer_publish_url}"`. But of course, that's just a slight variation on the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly adding a line break with `br`. Also, remove the `|` as it escapes everything indented below it, and remove the `<>` after `=` (which is a ruby call equivalent to `<%= %>`), <> will add whitespace before and after a tagged entity, but doesn't accomplish anything after a `=`.

```
 p Vous pouvez remonter votre offre en tête de liste afin de :
  * Booster la visibilité de votre offre
  * Bénéficier de 15 jours supplémentaires de diffusion
 br
  = @job_offer_publish_url`
```

Comment: I'm not working on a html.slim but a text.slim, so `p` and `br` tags are not understood as tags and are just printed as text.

Comment: Why are you using slim for clear text files? It isn't meant to be used that way and ERb, Curly or Mustache would be much better choice.

Comment: Not sure why this has an upvote, since the OP is not using HTML.